# Could some one explain why printing an option value showing "2: Object"?

Tags: angular, typescript

Hi Currently i have UI developed using angular 5 and typescript.
In one of my component i have a reactive form and in the component view i have select box form control. So what I want is whenever i choose a different option from the select box it should print the chosen value . so i have registered a function contactListChanged in my component class.

```
<select formControlName="contactList" [compareWith]="compareResource" (change)="contactListChanged($event)">
<option value="" disabled>{{ 'PLACEHOLDERS.CONTACT_LIST' | translate }}</option>
<option *ngFor="let contactList of contactLists" [ngValue]="contactList">{{ contactList.name }}</option>
</select>
```

in the component ts file

```
  contactListChanged($event){
    let a  = $event.target.value ;
    console.log(a);// prints 1: Object

    console.log(this.contactListControl.value); // prints Object {id: "1", name: "irish msisdn 1", total: 1000, displayName: "irish msisdn 2(1000)"}
  }
```

console.log(a) print the value "2: Object". However console.log(this.contactListControl.value); prints the value correctly. 
Object {id: "2", name: "irish msisdn 2", total: 1200, displayName: "irish msisdn 2(1200)"}

why is this behaviour ? i would expect console.log(a) to print the value
Object {id: "2", name: "irish msisdn 2", total: 1200, displayName: "irish msisdn 2(1200)"}

so what i want is to use [ngValue] and get the selected object in the method contactListChanged. How can i achieve it ?

really appreciate your help

thank you

Comment: Can you add screen of the console.log?

Comment: 1: Object                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
Object {id: "1", name: "irish msisdn 1", total: 1000, displayName: "irish msisdn 2(1000)"}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Javascript by default does not support objects/arrays in the `value` attribute of the `select` element. Angular has solved this issue using `ngValue`. When we use `ngValue` for objects in Angular, it sets the Javascript value of the `select` element to `id: Object` where `id` is the index of the selected option. and `Object` is a plain string value. So if you access the value of the selected option using plain Javascript (`$event.target.value`), you will receive `1: Object`, `2: Object`, etc. depending on the selected option. You can access the object by mapping the index to the options but Angular already does that for you.

Instead, you should access the selected value using Angular's native binding methods (`formControl` or `ngModel`) because Angular extracts the index (`id`) in the Javascript value (`id: Object`) and maps it to the index of the options in the `select` dropdown to get the object value.

So the correct way to access the value would be to use either `formControl` or `ngModel` to access the selected value. Since you are using reactive forms, in your case, you have already shown how to access the value.

```
contactListChanged() {
  const selectedValue = this.contactListControl.value;
  console.log(selectedValue);
}

get contactListControl() {
  return this.form.get('contactList');
}
```

(Source: [Angular codebase](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/f8096d499324cf0961f092944bbaedd05364eea1/packages/forms/src/directives/select_control_value_accessor.ts))

Answer (score 0):

Because you have binded contactList in  [ngValue]="contactList" that's why object the selected in  contactListChanged($event) to select the  name bind  contactList.name to ngValue as follows

```
<option *ngFor="let contactList of contactLists" [ngValue]="contactList.name">{{ contactList.name }}</option>
```

you can use value also if you only pass string.The only difference between two is that value is always string, where in ngValue you can pass object.

Answer (score 0):

It important to understand that when you get a value from an input ( radio, checkbox, options...), it's value will always be convert to `string` type.

And because `contactList` is an object, the console is showing you exactly what it is: an object that converted to string.

So if you want the value to identify the object you want, use the id  instead `[value]="contactList.id"` (or the property that specify each object) :

```
<option *ngFor="let contactList of contactLists" [value]="contactList.id">{{ contactList.name }}</option>
```

Then use the id to get the object you want:

```
contactListChanged($event) {
    let objId  = $event.target.value ;
    console.log(this.contactLists.find(x => x.id == objId));
}
```